# Retrieving Firebase Data Between Users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I would like to be able to retrieve messages between users at all times, however I can only seem to do this when I specifically reference the child node that I create when adding a new message to the backend (the child node is "+USER1PHONENUMBER:+USER2PHONENUMBER" and both users will write data to the same child node). This is fine for when a user goes into a contacts list and selects the contact as I can then get both user phone numbers and know which child node to use. I have done that here like this:

```
if (senderNumber > receiverNumber) {
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Passwords.FB_LINK).child("Message").child(username + ":" + binderContact.getNumber());

            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot msg : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Message message = msg.getValue(Message.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", "Message Received: " + message.getText());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Passwords.FB_LINK).child("Message").child(binderContact.getNumber() + ":" + username);

            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot msg : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Message message = msg.getValue(Message.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", "Message Received: " + message.getText());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

The thing is I would like to somehow receive the messages anytime my user receives a new message on a child node which indludes their phonenumber so then I can store this and display them in a list view with the contact details and also so I can create a notification on the users phone anytime they get a new message. Any ideas how this can be acheived? I do not really have any ideas at the moment.

I have the following Messages class structure:

```
public class Message {
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String text;
    private String time;
    private String timeCreated;
    private Boolean repeat;
    private String weekdays;
    public Message() {}

    public Message(String from, String to, String text, String time, String timeCreated, Boolean repeat, String weekdays) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.text = text;
        this.time = time;
        this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
        this.repeat = repeat;
        this.weekdays = weekdays;
    }
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public String getTimeCreated() {
        return timeCreated;
    }
    public Boolean getRepeat() {
        return repeat;
    }
    public String getWeekdays() {
        return weekdays;
    }


}
```

This is how I save the data to firebase and what it looks like on firebase end (username = phonenumber of the user):

```
                // Save message on backend
                if (senderNumber > receiverNumber) {
                    Firebase ref = new Firebase(Passwords.FB_LINK).child("Message").child(username + ":" + binderContact.getNumber()).child(currentTimeStamp);
                    Message msg = new Message(username, binderContact.getNumber(), message, hour + ":" + minute, currentTimeStamp, repeat, "M, D, W");
                    ref.setValue(msg);
                }
                else {
                    Firebase ref = new Firebase(Passwords.FB_LINK).child("Message").child(binderContact.getNumber() + ":" + username).child(currentTimeStamp);
                    Message msg = new Message(username, binderContact.getNumber(), message, hour + ":" + minute, currentTimeStamp, repeat, "M, D, W");
                    ref.setValue(msg);
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your data structure as text instead of a pic. Text makes it much faster and easier when we can copy and paste into our answer.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a super simplification of an answer;

```
messages
   message_id_0
     from: from_user_phone
     to: to_user_phone
     message: "Rock on, Garth"
   message_id_1
     from: from_user_phone
     to: to_user_phone
     message: "Rock on, Wayne"
```

All users observe the messages node for childAdded events.

When a new message is added it will be sent to all clients.

The client app examines the message to determine if 'to_user_phone' is that client and if so, display's it in the list.

The above is more conceptual as it's not the best structure; you could do something like this

```
users:
  user_info
    name
    phone
    shoe_size
  messages
    message_0
      from: from_user_phone
      message: "Planet 9 is called.. Planet 9"
```

then each user could observe their own messages node for incoming messages.

There's a bunch of different ways for a working structure so you'll need to explore what works for your situation.